# Can you use "of" before a date?

Tags: prepositions, dates

I just wondered if you could use "of" instead of "on" before a date in some instances. (Sorry if the question has already been asked, I couldn't find an answer).

For example:

- I won't attend the meeting of 3rd March. (From the French "la réunion du 3 mars").

Many thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: Yes, you can. I also spent a few minutes looking for another question on this (because I can't believe it hasn't already been asked), but couldn't locate one. Hopefully somebody else will have better luck. Is there a particular reason you doubted its validity?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! I visit StackExchange very often so I was surprised not to find the answer and it prompted me to create an account. 

I think I doubted its validity because I've been taught to use "on" before dates and didn't know if the "of" seemed natural to me because French is my native language. 

Thanks again for your help!